# Evaluate cumulative sum by category and reset when new day starts

Tags: python, pyspark

This is my PySpark Dataframe:

```
timestamp                   category   value
2000-10-11 11:00:00+00:00   A          1
2000-10-11 12:00:00+00:00   A          2
2000-10-12 13:00:00+00:00   A          1
2000-10-12 14:00:00+00:00   A          3
2000-10-11 14:00:00+00:00   B          1
2000-10-11 15:00:00+00:00   B          1
```

I want to get this result (differences between consecutive rows, grouped by `feed`):

```
timestamp                   category   value  cum_sum_by_date
2000-10-11 11:00:00+00:00   A          1      1
2000-10-11 12:00:00+00:00   A          2      3
2000-10-12 13:00:00+00:00   A          1      1
2000-10-12 14:00:00+00:00   A          3      4
2000-10-11 14:00:00+00:00   B          1      1
2000-10-11 15:00:00+00:00   B          1      2
```

I now how to get the cumulative sum just grouped by category, but I can not reset the counter on every new day:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

w = (Window.partitionBy('category').orderBy('timestamp')
      .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))

df = df.withColumn('cum_sum_by_category', f.sum('value').over(w))
df.show()
```

Comment: the question is still not clear.. could you pls explain further

Comment: why does the cumulative sum for row `2000-10-12 15:00:00+00:00   B   1` not reset?

Comment: Adding to @AdibP's question in comments, how do you know which row came before and which one after? Spark dataframes are not ordered. Or did you mean just go with the order of appearance ?

Comment: @AdibP: Whops, there was a typo. Sorry for that! I fixed it.

Comment: @anky: The dataframe should be ordered by timestamp and grouped by category.

Answer (score 1):

Your window `w` should be partitioned by the date of *timestamp* alongside the *category* column.  Use `to_date` function to get the date of *timestamp* and partition window `w` by it.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

w = (Window
     .partitionBy('category', f.to_date(f.col('timestamp')))
     .orderBy('timestamp')
     .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))
```